# in Python how to sum list of float

Tags: list

I am trying to sum the variable l, but instead of one number, i am getting lists of floats. 
Here is my code:

```
import re
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
hand = open(fname)
for line in hand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") : continue
    for lines in line:
        x = re.findall('^X\S*: ([0-9.]+)', line)
        l = map(float, x)
    print sum(l)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
total = 0
for line in hand:
   line = line.rstrip()
   if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") : continue
   x = re.findall('^X\S*: ([0-9.]+)', line)
   total = total + float(x[0])
print total
```

Comment: Thank you Stidgeon.
When i try the code i am getting an error: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number